# Computer won't restart or shut down

Tags: boot, suspend, shutdown

I have purchased a new laptop (HP Pavilion 11-n040ca x360; see [here](https://h20386.www2.hp.com/CanadaStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=K3Q30UA&opt=ABL&sel=NTB)).

At first I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it, but after the installation finished the computer refused to shutdown. I manually closed it by holding down the off-button. Then I opened it again, and Ubuntu worked great; except I can't shut-off, restart, or suspend; I must hold down the off-button every time.

I've waited for the 15.04 version, in the hope that it's some hardware issue that will be fixed, but I'm experiencing the same issue there as well.

Any help will be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem to yours, would try to shut down or restart but the computer would go a black screen and would not power off. My computer has the same cpu.  I found the solution is to blacklist a couple of drivers as found in this link http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=163126&start=20#p961212 .  OldFred from Ubuntu forums pointed me to the link.

Comment: Beautiful! Worked like a charm! I was stuck with this problem for months. Thank you very very much =)

Answer (score 0):

On the top right of your desktop screen there should be a cog icon. Clicking on it will bring up the shut down option. If you are trying other methods, please specify.